# How to make menu items of restricted pages visible to all user roles?

Tags: 8, users, navigation

On a website I'm working on, logged in users can post their feedback about some functionalities which the website provides. While only logged in users should have access to fill the form, invisibility of the menu item "Share your experience" caused to not many users navigate to this page and fill the form.

So what I need is to have the menu item being visible and when anonymous user navigated to this link Drupal will show them the login form automatically (which would be a different issue).

There was an [Always Visible](https://www.drupal.org/project/always_visible) module for Drupal 7. Now I want to know what technique should I use to make the menu item always visible in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah look, Always Visible already had an issue regarding D8: [Drupal 8 port of Always Visible](https://www.drupal.org/project/always_visible/issues/2535162). Some nice person created a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/DuaelFr/485feccad6d8d759c35f) you can easily build a custom module from to always display *all* menu items.

I've done that for you and put it on GitLab: [Always Visible (D8)](https://gitlab.com/leymannx/always_visible). Simply download the Zip file, unpack it, rename the folder to `always_visible` and put it into your `/modules/custom` folder, enable the module, done.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy. Just use `Menu Item Role Access` contributed module and check `Anonymous user` and `Authenticated user` roles for a particular menu item to make it visible for ALL! IMPORTANT: to make it working enable `Overwrite internal link target access check` in module config page (admin/config/menu-item-role-access).

Hope that this helps a lot of people!
Good luck!
Michal.