# nodeaccess hidden main menu navigation

Tags: users, navigation, 10

I have enabled the nodeaccess module for my Drupal 10 site and trying to figure out how to display the site menu navigation for certain user roles. In Drupal 7, there was a module called Always Visible, that allowed the menu navigation to display even when nodeaccess module was turned on. Is there an alternative module or a way to programmatically display the navigation for certain user roles?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make menu items of restricted pages visible to all user roles?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/262333/how-to-make-menu-items-of-restricted-pages-visible-to-all-user-roles)